# Azure Function v3 Time Trigger not running after deployment through zip deploy from VS 2019

Tags: azure-functions

I have a AF v3 with time trigger to each minute like `TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]`.

When I deployed the function into Azure from Visual Studio 2019 through Zip Deploy I can see in App Service - Function Execution Count Chart, that it does something. I have there count of execution 54 for a previous hour.
But when I go to Functions and the function itself I can't see any executions there nor invocations in the Monitor section (I have App Insights enabled).

Could someone help, please?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I already know what was the issue. The function run longer than the scheduled time (1 minute). When I increased the interval to 5 minutes all is good.